# Gulp tasks from separate files are not recognised

Tags: gulp

I am using following folder structure for my gulp tasks

```
app
   |-gulpfile.js //content of this given next
   |-build
   |   |-tasks
   |      |-watch.js //defines a task named "watch" which depends on task "watch-www" defined inside folder "www" below
   |-www
   |   |-gulpfile.js //not used
   |   |-build
   |       |-tasks
   |          |-watch-www.js //defines a task "watch-wwww"
```

The contents of the top level gulp file are

```
require('require-dir')('./www/build/tasks', {recursive: true});
require('require-dir')('./build/tasks');
```

When I run `gulp watch`, I get an error saying `Task 'watch-www' is not in your gulpfile`.

The contents of `watch.js` that contains the task `watch` are as below

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var paths = require('../paths');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');

// outputs changes to files to the console
function reportChange(event) {
  console.log('File ' + event.path + ' was ' + event.type + ', running tasks...');
}

gulp.task('watch', ['watch-www'], function() {
  gulp.watch(paths.api, [browserSync.reload]).on('change', reportChange);
  gulp.watch(paths.www, [browserSync.reload]).on('change', reportChange);
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your diagram shows the 'tasks' dir is under gulpfile.js?

Comment: @Bnaya thanks, fixed.

Comment: Did you check whether `watch-www.js` actually gets loaded?

Comment: How do I check that?

Comment: what is the content of watch-www?

Comment: The content of `watch-www` is a gulp task that depends on several other gulp tasks around transpiling ES6 code, minifying it and building code-maps. Also some other tasks around browsersync.